# Gateway address outside the subnet mask

Tags: networking, router, routing, ethernet

my router (DHCP disabled)

```
IP : 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

PC network card conf.

```
IP : 192.168.1.103
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.240
Gateway addres : 192.168.1.1
```

I can ping the gateway address `192.168.1.1` from the computer
Please let me know why this is so.
Should the netmask `255.255.255.240` set on the pc be blocking this?

Comment: What you didn't provide is your routes. Depending on the OS this could be provided with `netstat -nr`, `route -n`, `route print` or `ip route`.

Comment: I second the route request. You can have ”on-link” routes to any IP address, whether they are inside the subnet or not.

Comment: Anyway looking at the [answer-rather-than-an-edit](https://superuser.com/a/1716559/639799) part, I can't say much more. On Linux one can add a route with a gateway without route to the gateway first (thus defining the gateway's route at the same time as adding this route) by using the `onlink` parameter, but I don't know how Windows behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a "prefix route", which would be a *direct* route, will be derived and added when an address is configured with a subnet mask / prefix length (that is not `255.255.255.255` or `/32`).

[image]

(`192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` covers host IP 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254; in the case of IP / subnet mask `192.168.1.103 255.255.255.240`, the prefix route would be `192.168.1.96 255.255.255.240`, which covers host IP 192.168.1.97 - 192.168.1.110)

In the case of Ethernet, a direct route means that traffics for destination IPs covered by it will be encapsulated in Ethernet frame with Layer 2 destination address (a.k.a. destination MAC address) of those hosts themselves, in which case the address is learned through the means of [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) (or [NDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) in the case of IPv6). Direct route is (usually, at least, if not always) defined with / bound to an interface and that's how the OS knows where to send the ARP request (which is a broadcast traffic).

For destination IPs covered by an *indirect* route, the destination L2/MAC address would be the that of the gateway / nexthop. So normally you need to have a direct route configured for the gateway / nexthop in the *indirect* routes you have in your system.

When the prefix route derived does not cover the default gateway (which means gateway in the default route, which is `0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` and essentially always an indirect route in the case of Ethernet), then it's quite natural that the OS have no idea where to send the traffics (to either your default gateway or the Internet).

I'm not sure if Windows actually allows you to set / configure an invalid gateway / route (i.e. indirect route with gateway that is not covered by any direct route) though. Perhaps it does, perhaps you only thought you were using `192.168.1.1` as the default gateway. In any case, technically / generally speaking, you just need to either add a direct route for it manually, or fix your subnet mask / prefix length so that the prefix route covers the desired gateway.

P.S. AFAIK, `On-link` in the above screenshot indicates that a specific route is a direct route, and indirect routes are those that has an IP in the `gateway` field. (It might also be worth mentioning that in some cases the "(in)direct-ness" could be considered bogus, for example when the interface is not an Ethernet NIC but a virtual interface that leads to an L3 VPN tunnel.) And apparently, Windows uses the IP configured on a specific interface to represent the interface in the route print.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Windows automatically assumes the gateway is on-link, even if it falls outside the subnet. Though I don't know if it explicitly autoconfigures a /32 "on-link" route or if it just does that silently.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant "I *can't* ping the gateway address".

A gateway address must *always* be located within the subnet of the host needing to use it. `192.168.1.103/255.255.255.240` defines a subnet of `192.168.1.96/28`, with IP addresses from `192.168.1.96` to `192.168.1.111` (the first and the last aren't usable for hosts). 192.168.1.1 is outside that subnet so it cannot be used as a gateway.

You should always use the same subnet mask for all devices on the same subnet. You can read all there is to subnetting, masks and prefixes in [this Q&A](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers).

Answer (score -1):

The netmask for a device is only used to make routing decisions for outgoing traffic, but it will never "block" any traffic.

The netmask defines the range of IP address that are part of the subnet that the host is a part of. Hosts on the same subnet can communicate directly with each other.  So, if the destination IP of a packet is within the subnet of the host the host will send that packet directly to the destination host.

On the other hand, if the destination IP is not within the host's subnet, it will need to rely on its routing table to determine where to send the packet.  It most simple cases, the routing table will have a default route to the gateway router.  That router will then route the traffic appropriately.

In your situation, your router and your host have different understandings of what their subnet is, which is confusing, but in the end the host will send the traffic to the default gateway router and things will work.